SQL to predict remaining thickness (Postgres)
I have a table set up with the remaining length of a board (Board_Name). It is being cut into varying lengths and each row (Position) records how much was cut (Removal) and the remaining length of the board (Length).
I am trying to predict how many more boards I will get out of the remaining wood using the average lengths of all previously cut boards from the same board.
Initial table:

Target table:

At first I tried using window functions, but that does not allow me to retain the latest information to carry down over rows where the value is NULL:
I think I need a recursive SQL query in Postgres to achieve this, but cannot figure out how to use window functions within a recursive query.


You need to make the question title match what you describe in the question, namely you are looking for remaining length not thickness. 2) Do not uses images for textual data, copy and paste as text into question text.  3) I see nothing that shows the number of lengths cut that produced the Removal number nor the kerf of the cut. Without those I can't see how you can predict number of boards remaining.

